# Wrapping a shell script with tee

Tags: bash, io-redirection, stdout, tee

There is a bash script which prints some logs and allows some arguments. The script prints the logs to STDOUT.
Let's say the script's name is `AAA.sh`

I'd also like to make the script to print the logs to `STDOUT` and a `file`.
This can be done with `tee`.

```
$ AAA.sh -a -b --c=d | tee 2012-07-03-080000.log
```

But my team often forgets to pipe the output to `tee`. We should save the logs to file.
So I'd like to wrap the script with `tee`.

What I want to do is

```
$ WrapAAAwithTee.sh -a -b --c=d
```

Then AAAwithTee.sh should print the log to STDOUT and a log file.
How can I wrap the AAA.sh?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This script will work better than the previous answer:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec AAA.sh "$@" | tee "$(date +'%F-%H%M%S').log"
```

This will work properly with spaces and give a unique name to the log file, based on the current time. The `exec` also makes it a little more efficient and removes the wrapper from your process tree, once the child has launched.

Answer (score 2):

Your `WrapAAAwithTee.sh` should contain:

```
#!/bin/bash
AAA.sh "$@" | tee 2012-07-03-080000.log
```

`tee` will function normally inside a script, and `"$@"` will contain all parent arguments.

Comment: oh, thank you. Could you also know how to generate the datetime format dynamically?

Comment: Use ` ... | tee $(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S").log`. If you want to have the log files all at at fixed directory, put an absolute path in front of the(generated) filename.

Comment: No no no no! Always use `"$@"` (with quotes) or you will have horrible problems as soon as you try a parameter with a space in it!