# Script output depending on parameter

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I have script that prints out few lines of text. This text is used as configuration by other process.

When I normally run program I redirect standard output to file which is fine:

```
./generateConfig.sh > normal.cfg
```

But the problem is that normal.cfg is really constant and I would like to give user a choice to print to file or on the screen by providing additional parameter (like -o, without parameter arguments).

if the script content is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "8.8.8.8"
```

How would I parametrize output so that depending on args it will print out to file or stdout?

This does not seem to work:

```
#!/bin/bash
output="/dev/stdout"
if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
  output="normal.cfg"
fi
echo "8.8.8.8" > $output
```

Comment: Your attempt seems to be correct, thought. It should work. What happens when you run it?

Comment: @muru, on Linux, `echo > /dev/stdout` would reopen the file stdout goes to from scratch. For a regular file, that would overwrite it. For a socket, that would fail. (it could also be affected by the way shells perform redirection (like if they  move fd 1 to something else before opening /dev/stdout).

Comment: Related: [Conditional pipeline](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38310)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several approaches:

### A function

```
 #! /bin/sh -
 [ "$#" -gt 0 ] && redir=true || redir=false
 redir() if "$redir"; then "$@" > normal.cfg; else "$@"; fi

 redir echo 8.8.8.8
```

### An alias:

```
 #! /bin/sh -
 [ -z "$BASH_VERSION" ] || shopt -s expand_aliases

 [ "$#" -gt 0 ] && alias redir='>normal.cfg' || alias redir=

 redir echo 8.8.8.8
```

(won't work with `posh` which disabled aliases, or if *sourced* (with the `.` command) in AT&T implementations of `ksh`).

### A dedicated file descriptor:

```
 #! /bin/sh -
 [ "$#" -gt 0 ] && exec 3> normal.cfg || exec 3>&1

 echo 8.8.8.8 >&3
```

(beware that apart from ksh93, not many shells set the close-on-exec flag on that fd 3, so you may want to close it for commands you execute by hand)

Comment: I'm curious: why would you use `sh` as for the shebang in the alias examlpe?

Comment: @muru, because that would work with most sh and all systems have a sh, while not so many have bash. For those unlucky enough to have bash as their sh, I add the workaround for bash that doesn't expand aliases in non-interactive shells.

Comment: So aliases are on by default in noninteractive ksh, zsh, dash, etc.?

Comment: @muru, yes. There are some contexts where some aliases are not expanded in some shells (like in `sh -c '...'` or sourced files), but the above should work on most systems. Some shells even allowed exporting aliases. POSIX leaves it unspecified whether aliases are expanded or not in non-interactive shells.

Answer (score 3):

You can redirect the output of the whole script using `exec`.

```
#! /bin/bash

if [[ $1 = -o ]]
then
    exec > "$2"
fi

echo "8.8.8.8"
```

Now, if you run the script with `-o foo`, the output will be in the file `foo`.

```
$ ./foo.sh 
8.8.8.8
$ ./foo.sh -o bar
$ cat bar
8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Thanks I was not aware of exec command. Thanks for explanation

Answer (score -1):

Try with:

```
#!/bin/bash
output="normal.cfg"
if [ $# -gt 0 ]; 
 then
  echo "8.8.8.8" > $output
 else
  echo "8.8.8.8"
fi
```

If you want to do something more complex, you may try `tee` command: [see example here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42213/wrapping-a-shell-script-with-tee?rq=1).

Comment: Appreciate but I am looking for something more advanced. The script above is just example, in fact it's more complex.